# Was Jerry expecting Katie to show up in the movie "Eight Below"?

Tags: character, dialogue, eight-below

When Katie first arrives on the base, Jerry runs to the plane to help her down. He can be heard saying, "I didn't expect to see you this year!" Katie replies, "Yeah, well I guess you got lucky." This implies that he didn't expect to see her.

However, later on that night in Katie's room... Jerry brings her a bowl of ice cream stating that it's strawberry (her favorite). She replies by reminding him that strawberry is his favorite flavor, and he says.. "Yeah, well you got here early. I didn't have time to go shopping." This implies in a playful way that he *DID* expect her, and that she showed up early.

Now, I assume it's just him being sarcastic. He obviously can't go shopping in the Arctic.  It could be just the way that Paul Walker delivers the line of dialogue that throws me off.  However, was Jerry expecting Katie to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is the scene](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=eight-below) in question:

> **Knock, knock.**
>   **Jerry**: Hey.
>   **Katie**: Hey.
>   **Jerry**: l warmed up some of your favorite ice cream. Strawberry.
>   **Katie**: That's your favorite ice cream.
>   **Jerry**: Yeah, well, you got here
>   early. I didn't have time to go shopping.

I took this to mean he's being playful with her. He offers her the ice cream and jokingly refers to it being her favourite. She points out it's actually *his* favourite, to which he responds he didn't have time to go shopping.

The final line, where he mentions her getting here early, appears to be nothing more than a playful, charming line from Walker as if to suggest she was *earlier* than expected - she was, she wasn't expected at all!

He *wasn't* expecting her - if he was, he *would* have gone shopping and bought *her* favourite flavour. As he didn't know she was coming, he hadn't done that so all he had was *his* favourite flavour of ice cream, which he defended by playfully accusing her of being early.